# how to configure apache server to allow other users to start/stop

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I see inside config file the option to start server with certain username/group i.e.:

User c0mrade
Group c0m

Now if I start the server with my username, nobody can stop it except me. How can I configure server that is startable/stopable by certain other users or groups as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add these users to sudo group
2. Make sure there is line in /etc/sudoers like `%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`
3. Under normal user execute `sudo /etc/init.d/your-httpd [stop|start|restart]`